# Simple wrapper function for WinInet post (in Delphi)

Tags: delphi, indy, wininet

Here is a way to do an HTTP post using Indy, in one line, more or less:

```
Response := FIdHttp.Post(URL, StringStream);
```

Is there a function out there (function, not library) that allows the equivalent to be done using WinInet?

Preferably, a function that resembles this:

```
function PostUsingWinInet(const URL, Data :string; SSL :boolean) :string;
```

I do not want to reinvent the wheel and write my own wrapper function if one already exists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See this Stack Overflow question: [How to send a HTTP POST Request in Delphi using WinInet api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823542/how-to-send-a-http-post-request-in-delphi-using-wininet-api).

Comment: Thanks, but the function posted there is not self-contained;  it relies on other functions the author wrote but did not post.

Comment: No, it is not. It uses only WinInet and Sysutils and maybe Windows (can't bother to check).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Synapse](http://www.synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/start).  Yes it is a library, but not a component one. It exposes classes and simple blocking functions that take the pain out of TCP/IP communication.

For instance, a small program which performs a post (ssl is supported btw):

```
uses
  httpsend;

var
  url : string;
  urldata : string;
  PostData : tMemoryStream;

begin
    :
  if HttpPostURL(URL, URLData, PostData) then
    Writeln('Sent');
end.
```