# How do I ignore the response of a POST request in Indy?

Tags: delphi, indy

How can I send a POST request with Indy (10) and then **ignore** the result(s) or lowlevel API `recv`?
I'm asking because I do not need the results and I would like to save bandwidth.

Comment: Done. It would be better in the future if you are more careful with your questions and be specific with them, so that the comments and downvotes don't get there in the first place. (We shouldn't have to fix your questions in order to save you from closure or downvotes, if you put more effort into asking them in the first place.) :-)

Comment: Removed my downvote and comment, but cannot remove my close vote. You do need to be careful how you word your question, because you get exactly what you ask.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question. Do you want to use Post() function asynchronously and not wait for it to return result? If so, I doubt that is possible with Indy, only way that I see is to execute IdHTTP.Post() in separate thread, or to go with another component that can do async post (e.g. ICS: [link](http://www.overbyte.be))

Comment: @MarkoPaunovic this would be a workaround, but I'm asking in a manner of bandwith waste.

Comment: Hmm, I doubt thats possible with existing components, atleast the ones I know for. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823542/how-to-send-a-http-post-request-in-delphi-using-wininet-api) and the code in answer. Try to strip the part where he waits for response after sending request.

Comment: I think this question essentially asks to complete this analogy: `GET : HEAD :: POST : ___`.

Comment: Is the server yours? Are you able to modify the code of the server? Because if so, the easy solution is to not send back anything in the first place. But chances are it's not yours.

Comment: Not the server is not mine and it's https. Since I know all the POST parameters I don't need get before. Thanks for your tips tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `TIdHTTP`, you cannot ignore the `recv()`, but you can ignore the response data, at least.  Call the overloaded version of `Post()` that takes a `AResponseContent: TStream` parameter as output, and set the `TStream` to `nil`.  `TIdHTTP` will still read the response headers and body data from the socket, but it will discard whatever it reads for the body.  This is important if HTTP keep-alives are used, as it keeps the connection in sync so subsequent HTTP requests can continue being sent on the same connection.  If you are not using HTTP keep-alives, then the connection will be closed before `Post()` exits.  If you want to close the connection sooner, you can try raising an exception in the `TIdHTTP.OnWork` event when `AWorkMode` is `wmRead`, but that may not work very well, especially if HTTP redirects are used.

If you just want to send a POST request and ignore the response completely, you are better off using `TIdTCPClient` instead and just send your own POST request manually and then close the connection immediately.

Comment: Getting just the header is still less than the html content. Thank you for your answer.